# How to combine multiple excel files into 1 file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 excel files that have multiple tabs on each that I need to have each tab copied into one excel file, so that I can sort them into a particular order. Each tab has a different name (this ends up being about 130 tabs in the end). I have the code below that I tried and it changed the format of my graphs and added zeros on blank lines.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook


fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
End Sub
```

Is there a different code or a better way to try and get these in one file?

I have a macro the sorts the tab in the order I am needing them, but I cannot have the format of the tabs changing when I copy them into one workbook.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - I am not able to get the revised code to work. I am assuming that I was removing what was marked out. It will no longer allow for me to save that module.

Comment: Larissa, the code is exactly the same as what you originally posted, I only formatted, as code, a few lines above and one line below what you originally had marked as code. You can see the changes I did if you click the link "edited yesterday" above my name. If I would have answered your question, I would have done so in an answer post.